# Qual a melhor prática para saber se uma row existe em um SELECT no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, desempenho

Por exemplo, quando vamos checar se um usuário já está cadastrado na tabela, não precisamos de nenhum retorno de dados pela consulta, bastando apenas verificar se o número de *rows* é maior que 0 (`num_rows > 0`). Nos *scripts* e *frameworks* eu vejo utilizar para essa finalidade as seguintes consultas:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE usuario = 'exemplo';

SELECT usuario FROM tabela WHERE usuario = 'exemplo';

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabela WHERE usuario = 'exemplo';

SELECT COUNT(usuario) FROM tabela WHERE usuario = 'exemplo';

if (num_rows > 0)
//existe
else
//não existe
```

**Dúvida:**

Qual a melhor prática para se obter performance quando precisamos fazer uma consulta para saber se um valor em uma coluna já existe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61033/how-to-check-if-a-value-already-exists-to-avoid-duplicates Acho que aqui pode responder a sua pergunta.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` ou `COUNT(usuario)` são onerosos porque trazem dados, nesse caso sugiro o `COUNT(1)` ou então o `SELECT 0 FROM` do @bigown. E também sugiro tentar comparar as estratégias do banco para cada _query_ com `EXPLAIN SELECT` (basta acrescentar `EXPLAIN` na frente da _query_). Finalmente, tente criar um índice para o campo `usuario`, acredito que vai melhorar a performance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Precisa ver o objetivo que deseja, se realmente só quer saber se existe valores no banco de dados o mais simples entre essas opções seria:

```
SELECT 0 FROM tabela WHERE usuario = 'exemplo';
```

Vai fazer muito pouca diferença, se fizer, mas é melhor que todas as outras porque não tem que trazer nenhum dado do banco de dados, não tem que fazer nenhuma outra operação a não ser selecionar o linha.

Tem um jeito de saber. Faça o teste com todas as opções e veja qual é mais rápida. Pode mudar dependendo da versão.

Esta forma é ótima se você quer saber quantos já existem ou se você tem certeza que existirá 0 ou 1 elemento. Mas é péssima se pode existir vários porque ela retornará várias linhas sem necessidade. Aí o melhor seria:

```
SELECT COUNT(0) FROM tabela WHERE usuario = 'exemplo';
```

que no fundo é a mesma coisa que

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabela WHERE usuario = 'exemplo';
```

A vantagem desta forma é que ela já retorna o número de linhas achadas, portanto é garantido que o resultado só terá uma linha, menos tráfego gerado. E você pode ler o resultado da *query* para saber se tem mais de 0 linhas.

O que é mais vantajoso, ler o resultado ou pedir para a função indicar quantas linhas retornaram? Não sei, precisaria fazer um teste, mas duvido que encontre uma diferença que justifique a escolha de um ou outro. Essencialmente será o mesmo, será irrisório perto da operação toda, mesmo que execute isto 1 milhão de vezes.

A única questão desta forma é que ela não poderá usar o código de verificação proposto `if (num_rows > 0)`, afinal sempre o número de linhas nesta consulta será 1, já que o que retorna é a contagem de linhas que satisfazem a condição e não as linhas em si.

Se puder mudar essa verificação, então pode ser interessante retornar um booleano indicado a existência de linhas que correspondem à condição:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabela WHERE usuario = 'exemplo') > 0;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/IsExist.sql).

Esta forma retorna um booleano indicando se existem linhas.

Mas se o problema é ter duplicata, aí todos os jeitos estão errados. Você pode se envolver em uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101) e o resultado não será confiável.

Comment: dessa forma ele retorna um _boolean_ pra dizer se existe?

Comment: Não, o objetivo dele não é retornar isto um booleano. É bem verdade que a pergunta estrá mal feita e está procurando por uma diferença que será mínima na maior parte dos casos, mas não é especificado que deve retornar um booleano, e sim dar a chance de saber se existe ou não. Eu duvido inclusive que deva fazer isto desta forma, mas não vou entrar no mérito.

Comment: Ah, sim! Essa dúvida foi minha mesmo, nunca tinha visto a expressão dessa forma e achei interessante. Só uma última dúvida, se não retorna nada, essa expressão ainda tem alguma serventia?

Comment: Sim, ela ainda retorna quantidade de registros existentes que satisfazem a condição. Eu acabei de lembrar de uma coisa, então dá para fazer melhor.

Comment: Ah sim. Obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

O ideal seria:

```
SELECT usuario FROM tabela WHERE usuario = 'exemplo';
```

Considerando que o campo 'usuario' não se repetirá (será único ou primary key) e haverá um índice criado em cima desse campo, essa é a forma menos onerosa para o banco de dados.

Answer (score 4):

A opção [`LIMIT 1`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html) faz o SQL terminar quando achar o primeiro registro, é a forma mais rápida de verificar se um registro existe.

```
SELECT
  1
FROM
  tabela
WHERE
  usuario = 'exemplo'
LIMIT 1
;
```

Comment: E os outros registros duplicados ignorados... ele para no primeiro.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode tentar

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE usuario = 'exemplo')
```

ou

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tabela WHERE usuario = 'exemplo')
```

Answer (score 1):

Se é pra saber apenas se **`EXISTE ROW COM usuario = 'exemplo'`**, eu recomendo utilizar `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tabela where usuario = 'exemplo'`. Pois o `count(1)` irá percorrer a tabela, verificar se a condição é satisfeita, e ignorar as outras colunas da tabela. E quando você receber o resultado basta colocar `boolean existe = resultado > 0`